# Действие через кнопку при условии

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вкратце, мне нужно сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку удался объект к которому прикоснулся игрок (по коллизии грубо говоря), сама соль в том, что я не могу понять одну вещь.

Как мне сделать так, чтоб кнопка "понимала" что коллизия есть, и можно удалить обьект (обьектов много и они все рандомно спавнятся, через префаб тут не вариант)?

проще говоря, по сцене куча обьектов что заспавнились рандомно, и вот когда игрок получается касается коллизией одного из них (любого абсолютно) , мне по нажатию кнопки на экране нужно удалить именно этот объект (сенсорное управление).

Да, я знаю что весьма запутано, но я уже парюсь второй день с этим, а все понять не могу, много как пробовал уже, искал что-то похожее, но все ничего.
Я просто не могу понять, как такое провернуть, но уверен что возможно.

Костыли Велосипеды, никак иначе.

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен будет ли при таче именно колизия, но если єто и вправду коллизия а не какой-то другой метод, то приблизительно как-то так:

```
OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    Destroy(this);
}
```

код не проверял.

если же не существует отдельного ивента вроде коллизии который отвечает за тач, то будет что-то вроде:

```
void Update () {
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase.Equals(TouchPhase.Began)) {

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
            Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: а как мне дать ему понять какой объект ломать? мне нужно грубо говоря сделать ссылку из объекта который коллизией столкнулся с игроком

Comment: даный скрипт должен висеть на каждом из обьектов. Или же наоборот, висеть от должен на одном игроке, но дестроить обьект который висит внутри  `Collision col`. То есть что-то вроде `Destroy(col.gameObject);`